# Amazon DynamoDB [DDB] parallel scan - boto 3 - python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to do parallel scan but it looks like it processing sequentially and not fetching full records

My ddb has 400k records and i am trying to pull all records using DDB parallel scans.I want to use 40 threads

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                          region_name='us-east-1',
                          endpoint_url="https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                          aws_access_key_id="123",
                          aws_secret_access_key="456")
table = dynamodb.Table('solved_history')

last_evaluated_key = None

a = 0
while True:

    if last_evaluated_key:
        response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=last_evaluated_key)
        allResults = response['Items']
        for each in allResults:
            storeRespectively(each["decodedText"], each["base64StringOfImage"])
            a += 1
    else:
        response = table.scan(TotalSegments=40, Segment=39)
        allResults = response['Items']
        for each in allResults:
            storeRespectively(each["decodedText"], each["base64StringOfImage"])
            a += 1

    last_evaluated_key = response.get('LastEvaluatedKey')

    if not last_evaluated_key:
        break
print(a)
```

Comment: A parallel scan doesn't really make sense. Each request needs to know where the previous request ended. The only way to achieve what you are looking for is to have each thread have a known start and end point, but that requires both knowledge of the data and knowledge of the order in which it will be returned.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth Thanks just now figured that out, will post my solution

Comment: @JeyaKumar can you post your solution please ?